# Bounding box in opengl c programming

Tags: opengl, bounding-box

How can I create a bounding box around a 3d object that I've created in 3DS MAX, and then used it in an openGL application? I need the bounding box for collision detection, but I don't understand how to link a bounding box to an object. The function that creates the object is:

```
void drawR2D2(){
if (xrot <= 5.0) xrot = 5.0;

if (xrot >= 70.0) xrot = 70.0;

if (ztransKit2 >= 0.7) ztransKit2 = 0.7;

if (xtransS1 >= 0.2) xtransS1 = 0.2;

if (ztransKit2 <= 0.0) ztransKit2 = 0.0;

if (xtransS1 <= 0.0) xtransS1 = 0.0;


glPushMatrix();
    drawBodyR2();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 1.2, 0.0);
    glScalef(2.85, 2.85, 2.85);
    glRotatef(yrotHead, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    drawHeadR2();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(3.5, 3.5, 3.5);
    drawLegsR2();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-0.41, 0.45, 0.26);
    glScalef(1.4, 1.4, 1.4);
    glRotatef(xrotKit1, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    drawKit1R2();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-0.2, 0.5, 0.0 + ztransKit2);
    glScalef(2.0, 2.0, 2.0);
    glRotatef(zrotKit2, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    drawKit2R2();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-0.25 + xtransS1, 0.48, 0.45);
    glScalef(1.55, 1.55, 1.55);
    drawShield1R2();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-0.44 + xtransS2, 0.48, 0.37);
    glScalef(1.12, 1.12, 1.12);
    drawShield2R2();
glPopMatrix();
}
```

The other functions: *drawBodyR2()*,*drawHeadR2*, etc are the components of the entire object.

The code for the *drawBodyR2*, for example, is:

```
void drawBodyR2(){
InitModel("r2d2/body.obj", &body);//function to initialize the object
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, bodyId);
glmDraw(body, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_TEXTURE);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Can anyone show me how to create a bounding box around the object resulted from the **drawR2D2** function?

Comment: Collision has nothing to do with rendering. And OpenGL is for rendering. So unless you intend to draw this bounding box, OpenGL isn't going to help you.

Comment: @ NIcol Bolas Ok, but how to draw a bounding box around my object so when I move around my scene will not pas through other objects, that also must have a bounding box around them. The object that I've described above is my only moving object, controlled with the keyboard and mouse. Thanks.

Comment: Drawing a bounding box has *nothing* to do with moving it or keeping it from passing through something else.

Comment: Then how to detect collision in OpenGL?

Comment: What part of "OpenGL isn't going to help you" do you not understand? OpenGL is a *rendering system*. Collision detection is part of *physics*. Physics is about deciding where you want to put things. OpenGL is about displaying those things.

Comment: Ok, Nicol Bolas, nevermind. I understand that OpenGL does not have a "built in" collision detector, but my question was on how to "simulate" collision in OpenGL,  using the AABB algorithm for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "best" box you can build for collision detection is an oriented bounding box (OBB), that is the smallest possible box that fits the object. In order to do that you need to learn some maths (what eigenvectors are mainly) and use them for the OBB (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320142/oriented-bounding-box-is-misshapen-and-the-wrong-size-in-opengl) for a detailed explanation about OBB computation).

Note that:

1. OBB has nothing to do with OpenGL. You can compute the OBB/ABB having a model and never drawing it. Separate the tasks!
2. An OBB should never be computed twice for the same model, it is computational nonsensical. The ideal thing would be to precompute the coordinates of the 8 points forming the OBB of each of the objects you are going to draw and store them. Remember that this implies that whatever geometric transformation you apply to your object, you need to also apply it to the OBB.