# Major-axis of scatter plot shaped as ellipse in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, I have a 2-d scatter plot in (x,y) coordinates that is shaped as an ellipse. How can I obtain the major axis length?

I read somewhere that it has to do with the sqrt of the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix?

Comment: How did you plot the points? Which covariance matrix are you talking about?

Comment: I have 2 columns: x-coordinates and y-coordinates. I simply use the "plot" function. Say there are 1000 points which form an area of an ellipse. How do I proceed to obtain the major axis length?

Comment: This question probably fits better on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/)...

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, the eigenvectors will give you the mayor and  minor axis!

for this scenario, I like better the name computer scientist give to the eigenvalue decomposition: Principal Component analysis. The PCA will output 2 "principal components" or eigenvectors, being these some "new axis". This new axis will be the axis describing better the points, in an ellipsoid, the radii.

The following image shows what I mean. The red vectors are the eingenvectors.

[image]

For a step-by-step computation of the thing, check this other answer: [Oriented Bounding Box is Misshapen and the Wrong Size in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320142/oriented-bounding-box-is-misshapen-and-the-wrong-size-in-opengl)

The question is in openGL but the answer in MATLAB. Also, you just need half of the steps, as the other questions asks for a bounding box around the points, for which the OP needed these radii you talk about.